# How to connect radioButton ( <input type radio .. /> ) to call function when is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to connect radioButton

> `<input type radio .. />`

to call function when is checked ?
I need to record value of that button when it is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js:

```
<script>
function yourfunction()
{
    //function
}
</script>
<input id = "radio1" type = "radio" onclick = "yourfunction()" />
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$( '#radio1' ).click(function(e)
{
    //function
});
</script>
<input id = "radio1" type = "radio" />
```

You can add condition to check if the radio is chcecked or not, would look like

```
if ($( '#radio' ).attr('checked') == 'true')
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as you can see in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HVTsm/)

html:

```
<input type="radio" value="Test 1" /> Bullet 1 <br />
<input type="radio" value="Test 2" /> Bullet 2 <br />
<input type="radio" value="Test 3" /> Bullet 3 <br />
<input type="radio" value="Test 4" /> Bullet 4 <br />
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").click(function() {
        if ($(this + ":checked")) {
            alert($(this).val());
        }
    });
});​
```